# i need to send out a blog post in chunks to google translate and return it back

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-translate, google-translation-api

i need to send out a blog post in chunks preferably in sentences or words  to be translated and returned back  i already have the translation functiionality  i just need help with breaking it in chunks and getting it back how may i achieve this?

//["this","is","the","post"]
                var bod = a.body.split(" ");

```
            var counter = 0;


            while(counter < bod.length){

                counter++;


                var rang = bod.slice(counter, 10);


    //then translate the remaining portion with the code that is ready


                        console.log(rang);

                if(counter === bod.length || counter > bod.length){
                    console.log("end");
                    return;
                }



                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

Without going into the details of your request to google, do something similar to:

```
//Sample input
var body = 'The words I want to translate!';
//Sample result, will be an array containing translated words
var translated = translateData(body);

    //Sample function
    function translateData(body){
        var bodyArray = body.split(' ');
        var translatedData = [];
        for(var i = 0;i<bodyArray.Length;i++){
            //Do the translation here. var translated is the translation for the word
            var translated = GoogleTranslate(bodyArray[i]);
            translatedData.push(translated);
    }
        return translatedData;
}
```

Comment: Hey Jacob :D thanks for the reply i tried the code it works fine the only issue is that i think i need to split up the data into bigger chunks as im getting a 429 error code from google because i'm sending to many requests -.- would you suggest a work around?

Comment: If it's too many requests, than do a timeout between calls and delay each call.

for(var i = 0;i<numberChunks;i++)
{
setTimeout(sendChunks(chunk[i],2500); //delay 2.5 seconds between each call
}

This may be a very long time to wait. I'll guess that you're using a free tier and a paid tier accepts lager chunks.